# yo angular: Scaffolding issue, Which option to choose?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular but currently trying to setup an angular project. I executed `yo angular` and after initial steps I ended up at place where its asking following question:

```
? Overwrite package.json? (ynaxdH) 
  y) overwrite
  n) do not overwrite
  a) overwrite this and all others
  x) abort
  d) show the differences between the old and the new
  h) Help, list all options
  Answer:
```

I am not sure what option to really use. This is a brand new project. So I choose the option `d` to get an understanding of the difference.

? Overwrite package.json? show the differences between the old and the new

```
removed added

{
  "name": "client",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer-core": "^5.2.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-angular-templates": "^0.5.7",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^2.1.2",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.3",
    "grunt-jscs": "^1.8.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-ng-annotate": "^0.9.2",
    "grunt-postcss": "^0.5.5",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^3.0.0",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^2.0.0",
    "jit-grunt": "^0.9.1",
    "time-grunt": "^1.0.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js"
  }
}
```

basically following showed up as added:

```
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing what you did was run the generator without having installed all the necessary dependencies and so it created the package.json but exited halfway through.

There's really no harm in overwriting the package.json if you're starting a brand new project and haven't installed any dependencies yet.

The snippet of code that the generator is trying to install is actually a really handy feature of npm.

```
},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js"
}
```

`"test"` is a script that you can execute from the command line to run its associated task: `"karma start test/karma.conf.js"`. This task will execute unit tests and tell you that your app is working as expected. You can read more about karma here: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma

You may also choose to write your own scripts, in which case you can put them next to this one, though I imagine you'll mostly be using grunt to run all of your tasks.

```
},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js",
    "fun-script": "echo 'Hello world!"
}
```

I hope that helped :)